# Download ebook from Google Book API inside app

Tags: android, json, download, google-api

How to download ebook inside my application from provided `downloadLink` in Book API JSON response?

The sample response from Book API is as follows:

```
"accessInfo": {
    "country": "IN",
    "viewability": "ALL_PAGES",
    "embeddable": true,
    "publicDomain": false,
    "textToSpeechPermission": "ALLOWED",
    "epub": {
     "isAvailable": false
    },
    "pdf": {
     "isAvailable": true,
     "**downloadLink**": "http://books.google.co.in/books/download/Terms_of_Service.pdf?id=cxFSBQAAQBAJ&hl=&output=pdf&sig=ACfU3U0yfti1vuzQEs2RaiKIoHUihOzMLw&source=gbs_api"
    },
    "webReaderLink": "http://play.google.com/books/reader?id=cxFSBQAAQBAJ&hl=&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_api",
    "accessViewStatus": "FULL_PURCHASED",
    "quoteSharingAllowed": false
   }
```

Comment: Where exactly in the Documentation does it state that the Google Book api allows you to download an ebook stored in a users account?

Comment: No. Google Books API doesn't allow ebooks to be downloaded from links [Google Books API Docs](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/getting_started) @Prem Chand

Comment: @DaImTo but in response there is downloadLink that download the book in browser when you login same account in browser as book purchased account. Is there any solution to do same in side app??

Comment: Google Books APIs not provide any such direct link to download .epub files.So I think its not possible to download ebooks from My Library over there.If you have such link share in post I can check too.@PremChand

Comment: @PankajSharma "**downloadLink**": "http://books.google.co.in/books/download/Terms_of_Service.pdf?id=cxFSBQAAQBAJ&hl=&output=pdf&sig=ACfU3U0yfti1vuzQEs2RaiKIoHUihOzMLw&source=gbs_api"    please ckeck it.